# Why the amount of open source commits has decreased dramatically in 2009-2010 (according to ohloh.net)?

Tags: open-source, programming-languages

Declining commit graph at ohloh.net:

http://www.ohloh.net/languages/compare?commit=Update&l0=c&l10=lisp&l11=csharp&l12=-1&l1=html&l2=java&l3=php&l4=perl&l5=python&l6=haskell&l7=clojure&l8=scala&l9=ruby&measure=commits

Comment: Should be CW (at least).

Comment: May it be people just commit more changes in once changeset?

Comment: @sharptooth: Sounds plausible, with people shifting to things such as git and Mercurial, which seem to favor making less commits to the main repository, but the LOC stats are also going down: http://www.ohloh.net/languages/compare?commit=Update&l0=c&l10=lisp&l11=csharp&l12=-1&l1=html&l2=java&l3=php&l4=perl&l5=python&l6=haskell&l7=clojure&l8=scala&l9=ruby&measure=loc_changed

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: Hmmm. Mercurial... What if those guys used SVN and committed every time they changed a line fro the sake of not losing code? Now they use Mercurial and do those commits to their local repository. They change the same line 100500 times until the code works and only then push the aggregated change to the public repository. Is that realistic?

Comment: @sharptooth: That's exactly what I meant. Newer source control tools favor keeping small commits local and making big commits to the main repo. However, as you can see, the LOC stats I linked to are also dropping, so the amount of code actually changed is also dropping.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: I meant something different. Is it possible to collide several consequent changes of the same lines into one change before pushing to the public repository? If so when users changed to Mercurial they would not publish every single change of the same line, but instead acuumulate them and push the aggregated changeset.

Comment: @sharptooth: I guess that's a valid point, but I don't think it'd have such a big effect on the global stats. I doubt people commit a lot of single-line changes even when using SVN, since it's not exactly being nice to the people who go through all the commits afterwards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ohloh stopped automatically discovering new open source projects from code.google.com, sourceforge.net and other forges in January of 2010.

Also a large number of open source projects have since moved to github.com and many new ones start there. Ohloh has never automatically discovered new projects on github.com

So the substantial decline of the graph is due to a data problem on Ohloh's side.

This year, Ohloh has plans to start scraping automatically again.
They plan on covering code.google.com, sourceforge.net, github.com and other forges

Since Ohloh's data is based on commit history from source control, the graphs will retroactively correct themselves and all will be right again in the world.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the recession has caused people to focus more on work that pays, instead of their hobbies.